# Postgres Tables not creating even migration file exists

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, migration

I am new to rails the project which already have the migration files even though rake:db:migrate doesn't work

```
  $ rake db:migrate:status
/Users/frescoadmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:222: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
Starting up a new ElasticSearch client with 

 database: roorah_development

  Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
 --------------------------------------------------
up     20140822150851  Create users
up     20140822150950  Add devise to users
up     20140825181927  Add role to users
up     20140827184709  Add active and agree to tos to users
up     20140827192137  Create owners
up     20140827213949  Create renters
up     20140828003517  Create work histories
up     20140828180541  Add work history id to renters
up     20140828220343  Add bio and tagline to owners
up     20140828222402  Add active and bio and tagline to renters
up     20140828225430  Change active column name to owners
up     20140828230511  Create coapplicants
up     20140829172647  Add work history id to coapplicants
up     20140829174553  Add coapplicant id to renters
up     20140829175505  Remove renter id in coapplicants
up     20140829181221  Create rental histories
```

here we come to know that migration file exists but when i am giving rake db:migrate it's showing blank not creating

```
 FrescoMac002:Roorah frescoadmin$ rake db:migrate
/Users/frescoadmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:222: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
Starting up a new ElasticSearch client with 
FrescoMac002:Roorah frescoadmin$
```

in my DATABASE nothing is created , even i tried single migration file also like this

```
 rake db:migrate:up VERSION="20140822150851"
```

please help me out from this

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with

```
rake db:drop
```

& then

```
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```